# Best Way to Parse String Recursively With Various Fields

Tags: java, parsing, recursion

I need to parse an input for each value. Input size is not static

```
{"ruleId": 1000000,  "Group": "foo",  "Formula":    {"Aggregate": "foo",    "fields": 
    ["foo", "foo"],    "Children": 
    {"child": 
      []
    }   } }
```

Where each **child** can contain a list of **Formulas**, and each **Formula** can have a **Children**

What would be the best way to parse though this so that I can get every value and dig recursively into 'child' when needed?

Split, Regex, Tokenizer?

Comment: I guess this is Json response, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, looks like JSON, use a JSON parser (do not write your own). They are available for all major languages and platforms.

Comment: Yes, I'm given a string that was written in json form

Comment: Does anyone know a handy json parser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't parse it yourself use existing libraries like:

Google Gson: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

you can read more about different json parsers for java here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library

Answer (score 1):

The data you're showing is in the JSON format. You can use a [java JSON parser](http://www.json.org/java/) that will return you extracted data objects containing either terminal data fields (JSON Objects) or parent data fields (JSON Arrays). Check out step 2 of [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) example to see how to do this.

Also, you can download the .jar library for parsing [here](http://www.docjar.com/jar_detail/json-org.jar.html)